# WebStorm Angular warnings in inherited class templates

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

While using WebStorm 20193.2, I observe such warnings at Angular templates :

[image]

because those properties initialized on parent component instead of child

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dictionary-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dictionary-dropdown.component.html',
  ...
})
export class DictionaryDropdownComponent extends Dropdown implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...
```

I've tried to add to child class `implements <name of parent component>` but it didn't help.

Is there any solution to get rid of those *WebStorm warnings* ?

Comment: Is parent component defined in the same app, or in a library? Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40709 - does it look similar?

Comment: Yes, the parent component is from external library ( it's PrimeNG in my case ). And  yes your issue seems similar.

Comment: Me too getting the same warnings

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I removed the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file.

I hope this will help you too.